# Asp.Net Core run once function

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

When start Asp.Net Core I have to call the database through EntityFrameworkCore, I have to run it only once during user "Session"

Any suggests ?

Comment: You're just asking where to put code that should only be run once? Isn't that kind of obvious with Core? Where is all the other code that runs once?

Comment: Just run in `Startup.cs`

Comment: Yo maybe need scoped dependency https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

I usually use IHostedService. There is a [great article](https://andrewlock.net/running-async-tasks-on-app-startup-in-asp-net-core-3/) on this by [Andrew Lock](https://twitter.com/andrewlocknet).

In essence, what you want to do is implement the IHostedService interface and put your DB code in the StartAsync method.

```
public class MigratorHostedService: IHostedService
{
    // We need to inject the IServiceProvider so we can create 
    // the scoped service, MyDbContext
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public MigratorStartupFilter(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Create a new scope to retrieve scoped services
        using(var scope = _seviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            // Get the DbContext instance
            var myDbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();

            //Do the migration asynchronously
            await myDbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // noop
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

This code was taken directly from the article mentioned and is only placed here to answer the question asked. All credit must go to [Andrew Lock](https://twitter.com/andrewlocknet)

Comment: Updated link for ASP.NET Core 3.0: https://andrewlock.net/running-async-tasks-on-app-startup-in-asp-net-core-3/